# Why Jedis faster than spring redisTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, optimization, jedis

config:

```
<bean id="jedisPoolConfig" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig">
    <property name="maxIdle" value="300"/>  
    <property name="maxTotal" value="60000"/>  
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>  
</bean>



<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
    <property name="poolConfig" ref="jedisPoolConfig"></property>
    <property name="hostName" value="${redis.host}"></property>
    <property name="port" value="${redis.port}"></property>
    <property name="timeout" value="${redis.timeout}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="${redis.password}"></property>
    <property name="database" value="${redis.database.business}"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="keySerializer" class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer"></bean>
<bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate">
    <property name="keySerializer" ref="keySerializer"></property>
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jedisConnectionFactory"></property>
 </bean>
```

test case

```
    @Benchmark
public void jedis(TestBenchmark state) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
        jedis.hset("HA", "FA" + i, "VV" + i);
        jedis.close();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();

        jedis.hget("HA", "FA" + i);
        jedis.close();
    }

}



 @Benchmark
public void springTemplate(TestBenchmark state) {



    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        template.opsForHash().put("HA", "FA" + i, "VV" + i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        template.opsForHash().get("HA", "FA" + i);
    }

}
```

result :

```
# Run complete. Total time: 00:04:45

Benchmark                     Mode  Cnt        Score        Error  Units
TestBenchmark.jedis           avgt   20  4063712.941 ± 774497.669  us/op
TestBenchmark.springTemplate  avgt   20  8127876.567 ± 689718.613  us/op
```

if it is possible the spring wrap jedis in that create more java objects,or else have other reason?

### **stuffing** jedis:4063712.941 ±(99.9%) 774497.669 us/op [Average] (min, avg, max) = (3392560.609, 4063712.941, 7306286.674), stdev = 891912.667 CI (99.9%): [3289215.273, 4838210.610] (assumes normal distribution) spring-template 8127876.567 ±(99.9%) 689718.613 us/op [Average] (min, avg, max) = (7080667.847, 8127876.567, 9678719.917), stdev = 794280.981 CI (99.9%): [7438157.954, 8817595.181] (assumes normal distribution)

Comment: Did you swap it around and test again? Note that without the use of a proper benchmark harness the results are most likely off. Try [JMH](http://www.baeldung.com/java-microbenchmark-harness) for example.

Comment: tks @Thomas ,I did try  using JMH ,but it  integrate with spring context not well .
and I change     `Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();`  this line into loop.they using time nearly.so I wrote the wrong test case.The jedis using a single connect,springtemlate will get connect every time.
by the way ,springtemplate using the jedis connect factory